# select using sub select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with stats where each row includes player_id, game_id, and team_id. I am trying to create a query to return result where distinct games are returned where two or more players played together in a game on same team. I trying to create a select statement like this but obviously this is wrong.

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT * FROM stats AS t1 WHERE player_id IN (array)
 ) AS t2 
WHERE t1.game_id=t2.game_id AND t1.team_id=t2.team_id
```

Comment: What has this question to do with PHP? Can you please provide some data and an example result based on your data?

Comment: sorry, I'll try to remove the PHP tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has a id you can use this sql with **INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM stats t1
INNER JOIN stats t2 
  ON  t1.game_id=t2.game_id 
  AND t1.team_id=t2.team_id 
  AND t2.id <> t1.id
WHERE t1. player_id IN (array);
```

The you can modify the SELECT to **SELECT DISTINCT t1.game_id**

here my result of your table:

```
MariaDB [Bernd]> SELECT * FROM softball_stats;
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| sb_stats_id | player_id | game_id | sb_stats_team |
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|           1 |       100 |       1 |          1000 |
|           2 |       100 |       2 |          1000 |
|           3 |       100 |       3 |          1010 |
|           4 |       101 |       2 |          1000 |
|           5 |       102 |       3 |          1010 |
|           6 |       103 |       1 |          1000 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]> 
MariaDB [Bernd]> SELECT t1.*,t2.*
    -> FROM softball_stats t1
    -> INNER JOIN softball_stats t2 
    ->   ON  t1.game_id=t2.game_id 
    ->   AND t1.sb_stats_team=t2.sb_stats_team 
    ->   AND t2.sb_stats_id <> t1.sb_stats_id
    -> WHERE t1. player_id IN (100,101);
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
| sb_stats_id | player_id | game_id | sb_stats_team | sb_stats_id | player_id | game_id | sb_stats_team |
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|           4 |       101 |       2 |          1000 |           2 |       100 |       2 |          1000 |
|           2 |       100 |       2 |          1000 |           4 |       101 |       2 |          1000 |
|           3 |       100 |       3 |          1010 |           5 |       102 |       3 |          1010 |
|           1 |       100 |       1 |          1000 |           6 |       103 |       1 |          1000 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [Bernd]>
```

Comment: thanks, I don't think I assigned an id to the table. Each row has a primary key. Do I need to assign the entire table an id, or each column an id, or both?

Comment: Never mind, I used the row id and the query went through. The only problem was it returned EVERY game that either player played in, not just the games and teams that they both played in/on. It should return a very small set, probably like 2 or 3 results out of thousands of records.

Comment: @Jim - can you post the create of the table and some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and post the link then. i think you not must have a id field change the **id** tho the name of your primary key feldname. it is only to hide the combination to it self

Comment: the sqlfiddle.com site is not working for me. can't reach it. Here is an abbreviate create statement for my table

-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.5

-- Server version: 5.6.41-84.1
-- PHP Version: 7.3.27


-- Table structure for table `softball_stats`

CREATE TABLE `softball_stats` (
  `sb_stats_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `game_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sb_stats_team` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: -- Indexes for table `softball_stats`
--
ALTER TABLE `softball_stats`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sb_stats_id`),
  ADD KEY `player_id` (`player_id`),
  ADD KEY `sb_stats_team` (`sb_stats_team`),
  ADD KEY `game_id` (`game_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `softball_stats`
--
ALTER TABLE `softball_stats`
  MODIFY `sb_stats_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--

Comment: -- Constraints for dumped tables

ALTER TABLE `softball_stats`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `softball_stats_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `player` (`player_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `softball_stats_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`sb_stats_team`) REFERENCES `team` (`team_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `softball_stats_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES `game` (`game_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

Comment: @Jim - I have add a sample in my answer

Comment: thank you, your result appears to be what I'm looking for. Not sure why I received so many results when I ran it earlier in my phpMyAdmin SQL query box. Let me try again and will let you know

Comment: I am trying to export the result into a readable form to show you the result. I'm a novice although I've worked with phpMyAdmin for years. Is there a choice on export in phpMyAdmin I can use to format the data so it looks like the result you posted above? Or did you format that by hand/manually (or via terminal interface)?

Comment: I'm still receiving a large data set. I posted a screen shot of what my data looks like. I used the following query where player 10 played more than 100+ games and player 649 only played one game with player 10 yet hundreds of records in result

[link]http://deadmans.geocaches.org/images/sql_data.jpg
[code]
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
    -> FROM softball_stats t1
    -> INNER JOIN softball_stats t2 
    ->   ON  t1.game_id=t2.game_id 
    ->   AND t1.sb_stats_team=t2.sb_stats_team 
    ->   AND t2.sb_stats_id <> t1.sb_stats_id
    -> WHERE t1. player_id IN (10,649);[/code]

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. I needed to add this final line to your SELECT statement

-> WHERE t2. player_id IN (100,101);