# having id consistently appear in joined table select

Tags: mysql

This is a follow up question to my [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363497/select-using-sub-select/67363575).

I have the result I want but was wondering if there is a way for the player_id in first column of result to always be the same? I have created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f494b/13/0) to demonstrate what I mean. In the sqlfiddle result, I would like for player 10 to always be listed first so the statistics following are relevant to player 10, if that makes sense. Right now it appears that the first column depends on the order of entry in the table. The select statement is as follows:

```
SELECT 
t1.player_id,t1.sb_stats_id,t1.sb_stats_AB,t1.sb_stats_runs,
t1.sb_stats_hits,t1.sb_stats_HR,t1.sb_stats_team, 
t2.player_id,t2.sb_stats_team,t2.sb_stats_id  
FROM softball_stats t1 INNER JOIN softball_stats t2 
ON t1.game_id=t2.game_id AND t1.sb_stats_team=t2.sb_stats_team 
AND t1.sb_stats_id < t2.sb_stats_id  
WHERE t1.player_id IN (10,11) AND t2.player_id IN (10,11);
```

I've tried various group by, order by statements at the end but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: you can use "ORDER BY t1.player_id asc"

Comment: that doesn't work. player 11 is showing up in t1. I only want player 10 data to show in t1. Or in other words, I want to be able to always assign the first (or last) player in THE array to a specific table (in this case t1)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I needed to change the filter t1.sb_stats_id < t2.sb_stats_id to t1.player_id < t2.player_id in the select statement. Now the results are displaying in the t1 and t2 joined tables the way I want them to.